# Time for accepting connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I want to set a time for accepting connection from a socket.

When I use `s.accept()` it waits until a connection is established. I want my server accepts connections for a limited time then do the procedures then accepts connections again.

Pseduo code

```
Accept connection for 0.1 sec
Procedure()
Accept connection for 0.1 sec
Procedure()
.
.
.
```

Iam using python 3.7.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Why would you want that? What happens if your server is in procedure and something attempts a connection but gets refused as your server isn't even on it for that time? This sounds like a multithreading, or rather, in Python, multiprocessing problem.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple modification of the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) from `socket` library:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
TIMEOUT = 0.1

while True:
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            s.listen(1)
            s.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                print('Connected by', addr)
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    whatever_procedure(data)
    except socket.timeout:
        print(f'Timeout occurred after {TIMEOUT}')
        your_procedure_in_case_timeout()
```